# Ajax Not Receiving Response From My "Working PHP Script"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently making a Contact page using a mixture of Ajax, PHP and MySQL.
*A Few Quick Notes:*

- All of the PHP and AJAX code is working. The only thing that I can't get to work is the response coming from the PHP to the AJAX.
- This Contact page has been optimized so that, in the case that JavaScript is disabled on a browser. The page will use a simple POST method to complete the action.
- I have a few custom functions (e.g. n()) that have been declared earlier in the files that I'm providing clips from. Please just disregard these as they don't effect anything related to the issue.

A break down of each file can be found underneath each block of code.
**contact_page.php (where the magic happens)**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['l'])) {
if($_POST['l'] == 'php') { //This is related to the PHP version of the form validation. The code that handles the AJAX is farther down
$fd = $_POST['fd'];
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($fd)) { //Used to make sure all fields have been filled. Otherwise, return null.
    $fd[$i] = n($fd[$i],false);
    if(empty($fd[$i])) { $fd[$i] = null; }
$i++;
}

    if(isset($fd[0],$fd[1],$fd[2],$fd[3])) {
        if(filter_var($fd[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && strlen($fd[1]) > 6) {
            $q1 = "INSERT INTO contact_msg VALUES ('".$fd[0]."','".$fd[1]."','".$fd[2]."','".$fd[3]."',NOW(),'$date-$id');";
            $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc1,$q1);
            if($r1) {
                    $h = 'From: Jewl Photography Notifications <contact@jewl-photography.net>' . "\r\n" .
                         'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                         'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
                         'Reply-To: contact@jewl-photography.net' . "\r\n" .
                         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                    $m = m($fd[0],$fd[2],$fd[3],"$date-$id");
                    mail('nathan@lmartin.net','New Message From: '.$fd[0],$m,$h);
                        header('Location: https://jewl-photography.net/Contact?w=SNT');
            } else {
                header('Location: https://jewl-photography.net/Contact?w=INT_ERR');
            }
        } else {
            header('Location: https://jewl-photography.net/Contact?w=FLS_EMAIL');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: https://jewl-photography.net/Contact?w=MISS_ALL');
    }
}

//Below is the code that handles the AJAX

if($_POST['l'] == 'ajax') {
    if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['message'])) {
        $fd = array(n($_POST['name'],true),
                    n($_POST['email'],false),
                    n($_POST['subject'],false),
                    n($_POST['message'],false));

        if(filter_var($fd[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $q1 = "INSERT INTO example_table VALUES ('".$fd[0]."','".$fd[1]."','".$fd[2]."','".$fd[3]."',NOW(),'$date-$id');";
            $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc1,$q1);
            if($r1) {
                echo json_encode('SENT');
                $h = '
                **Header Info**
                ';
                $m = m($fd[0],$fd[2],$fd[3],"$date-$id");
                mail('example@example.net','New Message From: '.$fd[0],$m,$h);
                } else {
                echo json_encode('ERROR_ADD');
            }
        } else { echo json_encode('FALSE_EMAIL'); }
    } else { echo json_encode('NOT_ALL'); }
}
}
```

The contact_page.php is pretty simple.

1. It takes the POST info from the Ajax(shown below).
2. Runs it through a number of encoding functions (e.g. htmlspecialchars() and the like, represented by n() ).
3. Also tests for if certain requirements are met. If not, it should send a response back to the AJAX (see Step 6)
4. Adds it to a SQL table.
5. Sends an email to the moderator to let them know that a new message has been sent.
6. Then send's a response back to the Contact page using a json object: echo json_encode('Response Text Here');

Everything works except for step 6. For some reason, the AJAX refuses to receive the response. I'm not getting any PHP, SQL or JavaScript errors or warnings, and my Ajax (as you will see below) is using dataType JSON.

**Contact.php (the user-side contact page)**

```
            <script>
//This first half isn't ajax, skip down a few lines
//The very bottom of tis block of code is the form's html
                $(function() {

$('#fglk').submit(function() {
    var e = [];
    e[0] = $('#name').val();
    e[1] = $('#emal').val();
    e[2] = $('#subj').val();
    e[3] = $('#mesg').val();


    if(e[1].length > 6 && e[1].length < 255) {
        $('.err-span').removeClass('error');
        $('.err-span').html('');
    } else {
        $('.err-span').addClass('error');
        $('.err-span').html('Provide valid Email!');
        e[1] = null;
    }

   /**AJAX Related code \/ **/
    if(e[0] && e[1] && e[2] && e[3]) {
        var data = new Object();
        data.l       = 'ajax';
        data.name    = e[0];
        data.email   = e[1];
        data.subject = e[2];
        data.message = e[3];

        var options = new Object();
        options.data = data;
        options.dataType = 'json';
        options.type = 'post';
        options.success = function (response) {
            if(response == 'SENT') {
                $('.err-span').html('Sent!');
                $('.err-span').addClass('sent');
                $('.err-span').addClass('error');

            } else if(response == 'ERROR_ADD') {
                $('.err-span').html('An internal error prevented your message from being sent!');
                $('.err-span').addClass('error');

            } else if(response == 'NOT_ALL') {
                $('.err-span').html('Please fill out all fields!');
                $('.err-span').addClass('error');

            } else if(response == 'FALSE_EMAIL') {
                $('.err-span').html('You must provide a valid email!');
                $('.err-span').addClass('error');
            }
        };
        options.url = 'https://example.net/php/contact_page.php';

        $.ajax(options);
    } else {
    }
    return false;
});

});
            </script>
            <p style='color: red;'>
            <? //These $_GET parameters are for if raw PHP is used to send the message
            if($_GET['w'] == 'INT_ERR') {
                echo '**Some Text**';
            }
            if($_GET['w'] == 'FLS_EMAIL') {
                echo '**Some Text**';
            }
            if($_GET['w'] == 'MISS_ALL') {
                echo '**Some Text**';
            }
            if($_GET['w'] == 'SNT') {
                echo '**Some Text**';
            }
            ?>
            </p>
            <form action='https://example.net/php/contact_page.php?l=php' id='fglk' method='post'>
                <label>Full Name:</label><br><input type='text'  id='name' name='fd[]' required><br>
                <label>Email:</label><br><input type='email' id='emal' name='fd[]' required><br>
                <label>Subject:</label><br><input type='text'  id='subj' name='fd[]'><br>
                <label>Message:</label><br><textarea           id='mesg' name='fd[]' required></textarea><br>
                <span class='err-span'></span>
                <input type='submit' name='fd[]' value='Send'>
            </form>
```

Contact.php is pretty self explanatory.

1. It takes the info from the form.
2. Runs the email through a basic email validation
3. Passes it to a few JSON objects.
4. Runs those objects through the $.ajax() function.
5. Issues the **return false;** to prevent the form from sending and reloading the page.
6. After the PHP runs, the AJAX should then take the response and send a message that is written accordingly.

It doesn't throw any errors in my console. It will show an error if I provide an email that is under 6 chars long (this isn't related to the PHP code at all though). But won't show any of the responses.

**I've used the same AJAX code before and it's worked fine, the main difference is the PHP backend.**

**If you have any questions about the code please let me know!**

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: Try logging your response in your options.success function. Is it logging any response there?

Comment: is the email sent successfully?? .. and what is the output when `console.log(response)` on success function

Comment: Yes! In fact I have like fifty emails from all of the tests I've run XP! Also, I'm not getting anything logged in the console except for the AJAX POST statement: 'XHR POST: https://example.net/php/contact_page.php

Comment: I can't find the need of json while you just print out a plain text  you can just use `echo ('response text')`.. also `options.dataType = 'json';` and `header('Content-type: application/json');` you can use just one of them .. but with `echo('response text')` you'll no longer need any of them .. give it a try

Comment: Hey! It did something! this is the console log I received: '2018-12-19-377144SENT<script>alert("sent!");</script>'. It may seem like gibberish however, from the context I have of my website. I think I'll be able to make it into what I want! I'll let you know in a little bit!

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it worked! Thanks for catching that! To be honest I literally only did that because I had already tried everything else! I think the error was a mixture between using the JSON along with two "Unknown" echo statements that I had accidentally left in a few files that were being included into the contact_page.php file.
Thanks again! Do you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it for you?

Comment: No need for that ..Its enough to see your code working as you expect .. Have a great day @NathanMartin :-)